# How do you renew an expired Facebook access token?

Tags: facebook, oauth

I am working from [this reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), and trying to implement the OAuth protocol to allow users to log into my site via Facebook. However, Facebook's documentation is pretty terrible and it unclear in a few key parts.

It says that authorization takes three steps:

1. User authentication (redirect the user to `https://facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=...&redirect_uri=...`, and expect the `redirect_uri` page to be called back with a `code`). Works great!
2. App authorization (handled by Facebook, etc). Works great!
3. App authentication (On the callback page, grab the `code` you get and call `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=...&redirect_uri=...&client_secret=...&code=...`. The body of the response will include an `access_token` we need to do stuff)

I understand that with the `access_token`, I can call the APIs and such. But, what happens when it expires? I could get a new one, but by this point it will be many HTTP requests later, and I no longer have the `code` I used to get it in the first place. Do I have to store the `code` along side the `access_token`? Or, do I have to tell the user to log in again so I get a new `code` to get a new `access_token`?

Or, am I missing a key part here? I don't need an `offline_access` token, as I will only be polling data in response to user actions .

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When the `access_token` expires, the user will be seen as "logged out" by Facebook. Your app will go through the same process as the first time, but the user may not.

If the user hasn't revoked access to your app, and the user is logged into Facebook at the time, the App Authorization process will take care of itself, with no actions required by the user, and you will receive a new `access_token`.

If the user hasn't revoked access to your app, but isn't logged into Facebook, they will be presented with a Facebook login at the App Authorization step.  They won't be asked to give your app permission again, as Facebook knows that your app id is authorized by that user.

Finally, if the user has revoked access, then they will be presented with the original request for App Authorization, and you'll follow the original flow.

Essentially, you should consider the `access_token` as volatile, and not bother storing it, but using the `access_token` you receive as part of the user login process, which is happening behind the scenes all the time, and only involving the user when they log out of Facebook or revoke access to your application.

This is different than Twitter's OAuth with which you can store and re-use it.

Comment: So, wait, are you saying that I should be re-authenticating on every page load? Won't that double the number of requests to my server?

Comment: You only need to re-authenticate when the access_token expires. The response where you get the access_token also includes an expires parameter which is the number of seconds until the access_token expires.  You know when the token is issued so all you have to do is check to see if it's expired based on the number of seconds.  If it has, get a new one.  If it hasn't, then, keep using it.

Comment: Oh, okay. Fortunately, this is the conclusion I came to earlier. I simply insert a redirect to the beginning of the OAuth procedure when the token expires.

Comment: if the 60 day token is expired and the app hasn't been revoked will I need to use the current token from the signed request next time they come to the app to extend and update the old stored token? The reason I am storing is because I am doing daily scrape for user generated content which requires that token.

Comment: it will also expire if the user changed its password

Comment: For what it is worth I've found the "GET /debug_token" API call very useful when verifying whether an access token is still valid or not.  See especially https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/ and the section entitled, "Getting Info about Tokens and Debugging".  Important to note when hitting that API call that the "input_token" parameter is the access token of the user you're interrogating and the "access_token" parameter is the access token of your app.

Answer (score 5):

From the Facebook documentation linked in your question:

> Once the token expires, you will need to re-run the steps above to
>   generate a new code and access_token, although if the user has already
>   authorized your app, they will not be prompted to do so again.

When the `access_token` expires you will need to get a new one by going back through the same steps.  The user will have to log in again and you will have to get a new `code` and in turn, a new `access_token`.