# Renew Facebook access token with Koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, koala, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using `Koala` gem on on Ruby on Rails application

And I have the following code on the model I'm using to the the data through Koala:

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(token_secret)
friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
```

where `token_secret` comes from a field of my `users` table, saved on the login.

It works fine but after a couple minutes I get:

```
Koala::Facebook::APIError (OAuthException: Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1327438800. The current unix time is 1327442037.):
```

I found the way to renew this token in the front with the methods from the `Facebook JS SDK` but this method where I'm getting the list of friends is called on the controller.

How can I renew the `token_secret` using Koala? is this possible?

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710425/how-do-you-renew-an-expired-facebook-access-token

Answer (score 22):

I thought I'd answer this because it's something I just came across the need to do.

Koala added support for exchanging access tokens some time ago, here:
https://github.com/arsduo/koala/pull/166

So my User model now has something like the following:

```
def refresh_facebook_token
  # Checks the saved expiry time against the current time
  if facebook_token_expired? 

    # Get the new token
    new_token = facebook_oauth.exchange_access_token_info(token_secret)

    # Save the new token and its expiry over the old one
    self.token_secret = new_token['access_token']
    self.token_expiry = new_token['expires']
    save
  end
end

# Connect to Facebook via Koala's oauth
def facebook_oauth
  # Insert your own Facebook client ID and secret here
  @facebook_oauth ||= Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(client_id, client_secret)
end
```

Comment: I'll try that one, looks really good. But before I try I still have a couple questions: 1. I'm using Graph API `@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(accessToken)`... can I use `exchange_access_token_info` there or should I have to use `Koala::Facebook::OAuth` instead?

Comment: `exhange_access_token_info` is defined on `Koala::Facebook::OAuth`, so yes you must use it there.

Comment: I'd like to point out that in the above code (when I ran it just now with koala 1.6.0), new_token['expiry'] is a String of an integer number of seconds until the token expires ... you might want to convert it to a time when the token will expire if you're saving it.  Something like (Time.now + new_token['expires'].to_i)
HTH

Comment: Could you explain to me where you're getting token_secret from? I save the auth.credentials.token into a user field and tried passing it in but I'm fairly certain your token_secret is a different thing

Comment: @MichaelLiu it's not - it's the same token.

Comment: I was being silly :P was trying to exchange an expired access token.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Oooh yeah that could be a problem. I actually run a check on any access to Facebook that will call this method to refresh the token if the expiry is within a week, just to make sure it never expires.

Comment: When I execute exchange_access_token_info, I only get this as a response: Refreshed token info: {"access_token"=>"CAADCTfxcFqgBACDfL..."}. Why is there no 'expires' data field?

Comment: Are you sure that this methods works as intended? I receive new token but the 'expires' value decreases with time, so that `Time.now + new_token['expires'].to_i` actually points to the same initial token expire date... Do you have different behavior?

Comment: Something may have changed in Facebook's API if it no longer returns an `expires` field. It did work when I wrote it - there's no reason to assume that the token you get back is different than the one you have, if the one you have is sufficiently valid (ie. it expires in a decent length of time).

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Isn't the point to exchange the expired token... ? In this line `facebook_oauth.exchange_access_token_info(oauth_token)` I am getting the expired error `type: OAuthException, code: 190, error_subcode: 467` with this setup. it doesn't like me use my old `oauth_token` to exchange? (same as your `facebook_token`)

Comment: No. If the token is expired, the user must manually reauthorize it, by logging in again typically. The trick is to refresh tokens when theyre near expiry.

Comment: I think @Clam is referring to `facebook_token_expired?` which implies the token expires before renewal. Perhaps `facebook_token_expiring?` would be better unless I misunderstand.

Comment: Did you defined facebook_token_expired or it's some default method?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the oauth_token for a Facebook website application, you need to use the redirect-based Oauth process. It's a little complicated.  For a canvas app, it's simpler.  You can still use the redirect-based process for a canvas app, but it's better to parse it from the signed_request.

Every time a user loads your app in Facebook, they will land on your first page with a "signed_request" parameter.  This encrypted string must be parsed in your controller with a Koala object.  From the result, you can get a new oauth_token which should be valid for about two hours.  Here's how I do it.

```
 #Create a new koala Oauth object.
 oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(APP_ID, APP_SECRET) 

 #Get the new oauth_token from the signed request.
 your_new_oauth_token = oauth.parse_signed_request(params[:signed_request])["oauth_token"]
```

Comment: That's the problem, the application is not loading inside Facebook, It's just a web application using Facebook login, and at some point I use koala to retrieve the list of friends but if I don't load any other page on my app but the `friends` page the token is not updated, because I do this via `JS` on `FB.getLoginStatus(...)`