# Android SpringSocial - extend facebook token

Tags: android, facebook, spring-social

I am using spring social for Android. I want that once the user logs in, he would never be logged out of the application. How can we extends the facebook auth token indefinitely ?

Kind Regards

Comment: I want the the facebook auth token should never expire ? Is there a wat to do it ?

Comment: please read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/ hope it will help you

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710425/how-do-you-renew-an-expired-facebook-access-token