# user id not returning using facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
$this->_facebookObj = new Facebook($config); 
try
{
   $this->_userId = $this->_facebookObj->getUser();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
}
```

I've tried to run this sample code on my local machine with proper application id and secret key.
But response shows like I need an active access token. So i logged in to the Facebook,
then i get the user id successfully. 
but whenever I logged out from Facebook I couldn't run the above sample code. I think its because of session.

How do we run above API when the user's logged in session not available?

I tried the following :

```
$this->_facebookObj->getAccessToken();
$this->_facebookObj->setAccessToken();
```

before making the `getUser()` API.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6711354/1370485) as it explains how the authentication system work.

That said, here is how you can get the userId :

```
$facebook = new Facebook($config);

if (!$facebook->getUser())
{
    // Cannot access the user account
}

// try to access the user on the fb api
try
{
    $fbUser = $facebook->api('/me');
    $id = $fbUser['id'];
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    // Session expired, ask the user to log in again...
}
```

Comment: all right. but these processes are going on the back end service calls . So I've no way to show a log in box to user.
Is there any solution to get the access token when its expired?
And where these access token saved? probably in SESSION.
but I'm using a load balancer, which determine which server select under its layer. so each request going through the different servers 
so how do we get the same SESSION?